# Switching divs - javascript

Tags: javascript, navigation

(My java script is under basic, i’m in learning process)
I’m trying to make a menu navigation with some copy-paste from scripts i found here, but the result is not as perfect as i would like.

That’s the point, i want:

**Clicking one –div–**

1. Shows the –li–  from its –ul–
2. Others –div– get hidden
3. Clicking the –li– links doesn’t show others –div–, they keep hidden

**Clicking back the same –div–**

4. All –li– get hidden
5. Show all others –div– and –ul– (not the –li–)

Hope the question is clear, i appreciate any comment.

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul").click(function (evt) {      
        if(evt.target.tagName != 'UL') 
            return;
        $("li", this).toggle();
    });
});

$(".SHOW").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings("div").toggle();
  
  
});
```

```css
ul li{list-style: none;}
a {text-decoration: none;}
ul a {color: black;}
li a {color: #493A3A;; }

.GER, .ARG, .SPAIN {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 2px gray;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-heigth: 40px;
}

.ARG {left: 220px; top: 8px}
.SPAIN {left: 431px; top: 8px}

.GERLI, .ARGLI, .SPALI {font-size: 18px; height: 35px; line-height:36px; display:none}

.GERLI:nth-child(1) {background-color: yellow;}
.GERLI:nth-child(2) {background-color: Red;}
.GERLI:nth-child(3) {background-color: Black;}
.ARGLI:nth-child(1) {background-color: lightblue;}
.ARGLI:nth-child(2) {background-color: white;}
.ARGLI:nth-child(3) {background-color: lightblue;}
.SPALI:nth-child(1) {background-color: red;}
.SPALI:nth-child(2) {background-color: yellow;}
.SPALI:nth-child(3) {background-color: red;}

.GER:hover, .ARG:hover, .SPAIN:hover{background-color: lightgray;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="SHOW">
    <ul class="GER">Germany
        <li class="GERLI"><a href="http://blank.org/" target="_blank">Bratwurst</a></li>
        <li class="GERLI"><a href="http://blank.org/"target="_blank">Chucrut</a></li>
        <li class="GERLI"><a href="http://blank.org/"target="_blank">Ketchup</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="SHOW">
    <ul class="ARG">Argentina
        <li class="ARGLI"><a href="http://blank.org/"target="_blank">Churrasco</a></li>
        <li class="ARGLI"><a href="http://blank.org/"target="_blank">Mate</a></li>
        <li class="ARGLI"><a href="http://blank.org/" target="_blank">Pampa</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="SHOW">
    <ul class="SPAIN">Spain
        <li class="SPALI"><a href="http://blank.org/" target="_blank">Paella</a></li>
        <li class="SPALI"><a href="http://blank.org/" target="_blank">Flamenco</a></li>
        <li class="SPALI"><a href="http://blank.org/" target="_blank">Toros</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danielillo/v115dg7n/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arent thinking of these as boxes, when you click on a li you are actually clicking on the entire ul and the div. You need to not only specify which you are clicking on but you also need to start using IDs, classes can only go so far with javascript. I fixed it in here

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul").click(function (evt) {      
        if(evt.target.tagName != 'UL') 
            return;
        $("li", this).toggle();
    });
});

$(".GER").click(function(e){
  if(e.target.id === "GER")
   $(this).parent().siblings("div").toggle();  
});

$(".ARG").click(function(e){
  if(e.target.id === "ARG")
   $(this).parent().siblings("div").toggle();  
});

$(".SPAIN").click(function(e){
  if(e.target.id === "SPA")
   $(this).parent().siblings("div").toggle();  
});
```

```css
ul li{list-style: none;}
a {text-decoration: none;}
ul a {color: black;}
li a {color: #493A3A;; }

.GER, .ARG, .SPAIN {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 2px gray;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-heigth: 40px;
}

.ARG {left: 220px; top: 8px}
.SPAIN {left: 431px; top: 8px}

.GERLI, .ARGLI, .SPALI {font-size: 18px; height: 35px; line-height:36px; display:none}

.GERLI:nth-child(1) {background-color: yellow;}
.GERLI:nth-child(2) {background-color: Red;}
.GERLI:nth-child(3) {background-color: Black;}
.ARGLI:nth-child(1) {background-color: lightblue;}
.ARGLI:nth-child(2) {background-color: white;}
.ARGLI:nth-child(3) {background-color: lightblue;}
.SPALI:nth-child(1) {background-color: red;}
.SPALI:nth-child(2) {background-color: yellow;}
.SPALI:nth-child(3) {background-color: red;}

.GER:hover, .ARG:hover, .SPAIN:hover{background-color: lightgray;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="SHOW">
    <ul class="GER" id="GER">Germany
        <li class="GERLI"><a href="">Bratwurst</a></li>
        <li class="GERLI"><a href="">Chucrut</a></li>
        <li class="GERLI"><a href="">Ketchup</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="SHOW">
    <ul class="ARG" id="ARG">Argentina
        <li class="ARGLI"><a href="">Churrasco</a></li>
        <li class="ARGLI"><a href="">Mate</a></li>
        <li class="ARGLI"><a href="">Pampa</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="SHOW">
    <ul class="SPAIN" id="SPA">Spain
        <li class="SPALI"><a href="">Paella</a></li>
        <li class="SPALI"><a href="">Flamenco</a></li>
        <li class="SPALI"><a href="">Toros</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```